# Only Hide Menu Title in Joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

I want use Only icon in Menu Bar and don't show menu title check – http://screencast.com/t/E3pDOG8Mem

I have try the following CSS for hide menu title :-

```
li.item101 { display: none; }
```

But All Content for Hide in Menu bar. Check -  http://screencast.com/t/9cSMuhFyPW

My Requirement Only Hide Menu Title.

See the references - http://mashable.com/ see the icon - 
http://screencast.com/t/VwVoGpia

My Site Url:- http://www.test.guru99.com/

Comment: you want only search icon or only title?

Comment: if only icon then <i class="icon-search"></i>

Answer (score 0):

When you login to joomla and navigate to `Menus > click on the menu` and select the menu you would like to make a change to. 
Next click on the tab called `Link Type` from there you will see the following screen [image]

All you have to do is make sure `Add Menu Title` is set to **No**

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exclude this menu item from displaying in the menu. [image]